# How to SelectMany using a Django QuerySet?

Tags: django, django-queryset

Suppose I have two models, `A` and `B`, where an `A` can have multiple `B`s related to it. Given a QuerySet of `A` objects, how can I create a QuerySet containing all the `B` objects related to all these `A` objects?

For those who also happen to speak LINQ, I want something like this:

```
queryableOfA.SelectMany(a => a.Bs)
```

Even better would be an example of how to chain A -> B -> C, i.e. the following LINQ:

```
queryableOfA.SelectMany(a => a.Bs).SelectMany(b => b.Cs)
```

(returning a "queryset" of all `C` objects related to all the `A` objects through `B`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a queryset of A objects, you can do an 'in' startup query:

```
B.objects.filter(a__in=MyQueryset)
```

If you want to find all C objects that are related through B to A, you need to follow the relationships via the double-underscore syntax. Something like:

```
C.objects.filter(b__a__in=MyAQueryset)
```

Comment: A is a class encapsulating the model. filter() call on objects returns a query set that you are looking for. If you need one item use .get() but if multiple items will be found it will raise A.MultipleObjectsReturned error.